# Is it safe to use Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and Mongo Java Driver 3.12.12?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver, spring-mongo

## Context

I've an app with Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and need to connect it to Mongo Server v5.0. To do that Mongo Java Driver 3.12.x is required.

The application only use the Spring MongoTemplate.

## Question

I know the Mongo Driver is inside of Spring Data, but I can force the upgrade the Driver only. So, is it safe to do that?

Is there any compatibillity issue and documentation related to this?

I already tried and no error seems to appear but I can't really mesure it.

Thanks